How can this limit make sense of a dirac delta function
As we know $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {e}^{\iota kx} \,dx =2\pi \delta(k)$$
If we solve left hand side we get
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2\sin kx}{k}$$
So that means $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin kx}{\pi k} =\delta(k)$$
Now i want you to help me to get an intuition of this limit bieng a delta function
Because for it to be a delta function,it should be infinitely high at $0$ which is obvious here but it should also be zero at rest of points and that is what i am not getting.Tell me how i can think it to be Zero at all points.

Shouldn't it be $k\to\infty$ instead of $x\to\infty$?

You are asking for intuition of the wrong thing. I would say, instead, that these kinds limits are themselves crude (and misleading) intuitions of the functional analysis definition of the Direct delta function.

I have gone through many definitions of delta function and all make sense  of bieng an impulse like thing except this one

Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/834022/2451

Assuming
$$\delta_K(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-K}^K e^{i t x} \, dt=\frac{K}{\pi}\, \text{sinc}(K x)\tag{1}$$
then
$$\delta(x)=\lim\limits_{K\to\infty} \delta_K(x)\tag{2}$$
is indeed a valid analytic limit representation of the Dirac delta function (see this equivalent limit representation on the Wolfram Functions site).

The main lobe of $\delta_K(x)$ at $x=0$ gets narrower and taller as $K$ increases and $\lim\limits_{K\to\infty} \delta_K(0)=\infty$. While formula (1) for $\delta_K(x)$ doesn't evaluate to zero for $x\ne 0$, the other peaks and valleys get narrower and narrower but $\lim\limits_{K\to\infty} |\delta_K(x)|\ne\infty$ for $x\ne 0$, and consequently their weight goes to zero in the integral
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_K(x)\, f(x) \, dx=f(0)\tag{3}$$
as $K\to\infty$.

More precisely, the definition of $f_n(x)\to\delta(x)$ is
$$\forall \phi(x)\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)\, \phi(x) \, dx\to\phi(0)\tag{4}.$$

I believe this answer posted by user @reuns to one of my questions provides additional insight.
